# curl: How to see only the Request Headers when sending a request to the server?

Tags: curl

For `curl` as follows

```
curl <url> [options]
```

About the options:

- `-I` shows **only** the *Header Response*
- `-i` shows the *Header Response* (+ Body for `GET`)
- `-v` shows the *Header Response* and *Header Request* (+ Body for `GET`)

But...

**Question**

- How to see **only** the `Request Headers` when sending a request to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76756906/6309) is most certainly correct (as the `curl` lead developer!)

That means you can, as a workaround, process the verbose output of curl.

For example:

```bash
# Windows syntax
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v https://google.com 2>&1 | \
  grep "^> \S"  | sed "s/> //"  | awk "NR>3"

# Linux syntax
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v https://google.com 2>&1 | \
  grep '^> \S'  | sed 's/> //'  | awk 'NR>3'
```

Output: just the two headers:

```bash
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

The first three lines are removed:

```bash
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option for curl.